# Count Number of Values Based on Subgroups and 2 Columns

Tags: r, count, subset, data-manipulation

I was wondering if someone could help me produce this data in R.  It is rather complicated, and I am not sure how to start.  I apologize in advance if my question is not clear.  I am trying to create a unique dataset.  Essentially, I am trying to divide my data into four groups and count how many times an individual receives a certain value(s) within a group based on a certain column’s value.

I am looking at roll call data among legislators and how they voted.  Specifically, I have panel data with four variables:  *id* is the individual legislator’s identification number; the *struggle* variable is whether a member had trouble voting (dichotomous); *vote* indicates how the member voted (it can take on any value between 0 and 9 and it is a categorical variable); and *rollcall* is the roll call number or an id for each roll call.

First, I would like the data separated into two groups.  This separation would be based on whether member 999 (*id*) took any value for the vote column that equals 1 through 6. If he did, I would like all those roll call votes separated (and the members) in one category.  For all the remaining roll call votes (or does not equal 1 though 6), I would like all the roll call votes (and the members) in a separate group.

Second, I would like to separate both groups that were created from the above step (did member 999 take any value that equals 1-6 on the vote variable or not) by whether an individual legislator struggled to vote (*struggle*) or they did not struggle to vote. Thus, I would have four groups total.

Third, based on the vote variable, I would like to add up the total number times an individual legislator received either the values 7, 8, or 9 (in each four groups). Thus, I would have four new variables and values for each member

Here is an example of the data.

[image]

Here is the code to produce that table:

```
id=c(999,1,2, 999,1,2,999,1,2,999,1,2)
Struggle=c("NO", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "NO", "NO", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES")
Vote=c(1,9,1,9,0,1,2,9,9,9,9,1)
Rollcall=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
data=cbind("id", "Struggle", "Vote", "Rollcall")
```

I would like for it to look like the following:

[image]

A indicates the group in which member 999 received the value between 1-6 in the *rollcall* variable AND the legislator (*id*) struggled.

B indicates the group in which member 999 received the value between 1-6 in the *rollcall* variable & the legislator (*id*) did not struggled.

C indicates the group in which member 999 did not received the value between 1-6 in the *rollcall* variable & the legislator (*id*) struggled.

D indicates the group in which member 999 did not received the value between 1-6 in the *rollcall* variable & the legislator (*id*) did not struggled.

That number values in each group indicate the number of times a legislator received either a 7,8, or 9 in one of the four groups (A, B, C, or D).
Does anyone have any advice or potential code to produce this data?  I appreciate any assistance someone could provide.  Again, I apologize for this complicated question and any lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! From what I understand, every group `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D` in your output will satisfy two conditions: whether `id` = 999 has `Vote` in `1:6` or `7:9` and the second condition is whether `Struggle` is `YES` or `NO`.

For each group, the first condition evaluates to be the same. So, we first determine the first condition for each group and then `left_join` it to original `data` and then `summarize` it.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(id, Struggle, Vote, Rollcall)

data %>% 
  filter(id==999) %>% 
  mutate(cond = ifelse(Vote %in% 1:6, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  select(Rollcall, cond) %>% 
  left_join(data, by='Rollcall') %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(A = sum( (cond == TRUE) & (Struggle == 'YES') ),
            B = sum( (cond == TRUE) & (Struggle == 'NO') ),
            C = sum( (cond == FALSE) & (Struggle == 'YES') ),
            D = sum( (cond == FALSE) & (Struggle == 'NO') ))
```

- The first four lines of expression is evaluating the first condition (whether `Vote` of `999` is between 1 and 6 for each `Rollcall` group.
- We `left_join` that to original `data` and create 4 groups based on your criteria.

`Output`:

```
     id     A     B     C     D
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     1     1     2     0
3   999     0     2     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I think the code is really close, but it produces the total number of roll call votes that fall under each category (for a member).  I am interested in knowing how many roll call votes for a member contains a 7, 8, or a 9 for the vote value (in each of the 4 roll call categories).  Do you have any suggestions on how to do this last part?  Again, thank you and this is really close.

Comment: Dyllan, I'm not sure I understood. The way I see it, for members (`id`s) 1 and 2: their individual `Vote` values aren't considered at all because, the criterion for initial (step 1) sorting is the `Vote` value of `id` = 999.
If you want to know how many rollcall votes for each member (considering their own `Vote` values) then the distribution of output table would be different. Can you clarify?

Comment: I figured it out.  There was a coding error on my part!  Thank you!